# Having problems with MongoDB collection named 'auth'

Tags: mongodb

I have a **MongoDB** collection named 'auth', and when I run:

> db.auth.drop()

It of course conflicts with the **db.auth()** function that **MongoDB** provides.

Is there any other way to drop a collection?.

Comment: how did you inserted data? I don't think you can insert data in `auth` collection.

Comment: Using sails js waterline orm. I have a model named Auth and its collection/table name defaults to auth. I managed to change this default collection name, and of course I have no problems now. But I'm still wondering how to manipulate a collection with that name, because if an orm can do it, it is completely possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue arises when you try to access `auth` collection from *mongo shell* as it conflict with `db.auth()` you mentioned in the question. But using any driver you can perform CRUD on `auth` collection. I tried using its `java driver`, it works fine. That's why you faced no issue while using ORM as it is using any `mongo driver` internally.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly when this function was added, but mongosh supports [`db.getCollection`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection) now. I also have a collection named "auth" that I wanted to use with mongosh and was pulling out my hair until I stumbled upon this question.

I think [the documented example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/#example) was written with this SO question in mind :)